# Select in sql should give false if there is one record with 0. Possible?

Tags: sql

I am trying for a select statement in SQL Server 2005. I have columns "IsConfirmed" and "Amount".
My aim is to get Sum of all Amounts for each day along with a boolean value which should be calculated. If there is 0 as IsConfirmed, get the value of Isconfirmed for that day as 0 or if all records on that day are 1, give me 1. Is there a way for this kind of a solution in sql. Thank you in Advance..

```
Select sum(Amount) from RepAmount
where ComID = 1234
group by RD.Date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 
   sum(Amount),
   CASE WHEN SUM(CAST(IsConfirmed As int)) = COUNT(*) THEN
     1
   ELSE
     0
   END As IsConfirmed
from RepAmount
where ComID = 1234
group by RD.Date
```

Comment: Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator. This is what i get as an error :-(

Comment: @RAM just cast it to an int than.

Comment: Sorry. I got you.. Thank you!!